# How to make a WPF button behave like a WinForms Button?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, windows-10

I spent a long time looking for a way to make a boring WPF button be a little more interactive, and behave like a WinForms button, without having to implement that functionality myself. Here is an example of what I want:

Classic WPF button: [image]

*Windows 10* Winforms button: [image]

I even tried using `WindowsFormsHost` to add a WinForms Button to my WPF application like this:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="50" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <win:Button Text="Click" Left="50" Top="50" Size="50,20"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

But it appeared in a gray, old style: [image]

How can I add Windows 10 interactivity to my WPF buttons (like in Winforms), without having to implement that functionality myself?

***Update:***
By "more interactive" I mean to have a thick blue border when in focus, and behave with smooth transitions, like a Windows 10 system button.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I updated my question

Comment: Ok, I now understand the border issue, but what specifically does "behave with smooth transitions"  mean, which transitions are you talking about?

Comment: Every framework has its own benifits and drawbacks. So, is WPF. WPF is better in every aspect. In winforms you have a little control over the appearance of a control. In WPF you have that benifit. So, it might be possible that Microsoft has left it with default styling without the blue border. So, as mentioned in the answer below by @H.B. you need to override the template. If you are thinking that you don't want to implement functionalities yourself, then please stay far away from WPF and use Winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By "more interactive" I mean to have a thick blue border when in focus, and behave with smooth transitions, like a Windows 10 system button.

It's just a matter of [styling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx). Fancy things will require you to override the `Template` in the style. To do transitions one usually uses the [`VisualStateManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx). (Most controls already have some pre-defined states, so you do not need to invoke `VisualStateManager.GoToElementState` yourself. The button states along with a usage example style can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328(v=vs.110).aspx).)